# How to open a pdf file at a specifc page with information in a word table

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have a Word document that contains a table with 3 columns. I'm trying to create a macro that will open a pdf file (name stored in columns 2) at the page number in column 3.

I found a macro in Excel that will open it automatically when I select the page number cell, but nothing in Word. Lots of users are using the Word document and don't want to switch to Excel.

Best will be to activate the macro with a keybord shortcut and if in the table, it will open the file at the page specified in the row where the cursor is.  If cursor is not in the table, an error could show.

Thanks.

> [EDIT]

Here is the code for the Excel macro.  Note that the Adobe Reader path and program is store in cell B1 and the file is in cell B2 in this example.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Row > 4 And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value > 0 Then

      vAdobe = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
      vDocument = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)

      vPage = Target.Value

      result = Shell(vAdobe & " /A ""page=" & vPage & """ " & vDocument, vbNormalFocus)

   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if you show here that code which you have found someone could possibly help. give yourself a chance... :)

Comment: @KazJaw: `give yourself a chance...` I like that line! :)

Comment: @KazJaw: I edited the post with the code from the Excel macro.

Comment: This code brings up, "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" for this line: code
Dim aRow As Row
code Also, where do you define the document location?

Comment: Not a place for questions and little notations. Use comments instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Sub OpenPDF()
Dim aRow As Row
Dim vDocument As String
Dim vPage As String
Dim vAdobe As String
Dim result As Long

vAdobe = <File path to Acrobat.exe here.>
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    Set aRow = Selection.Range.Rows(1)
    vDocument = Trim(Replace(Replace(aRow.Cells(2).Range.Text, "", ""), vbCr, ""))
    vPage = Trim(Replace(Replace(aRow.Cells(3).Range.Text, "", ""), vbCr, ""))
    result = Shell(vAdobe & " /A ""page=" & vPage & """ " & vDocument, vbNormalFocus)
Else: 'Some error message here.
End If
End Sub
```

You may need to play with those Replace methods; I found it necessary to remove some table characters that were appearing at the end of any text pulled from the table cell.

Another option that requires setting a reference can be found here: http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2012/07/vba-macro-to-open-pdf-file.html

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I was looking for. It is working just fine. I just need to add some validations to avoid error. The other site is indeed a great reference. Thanks again!!